# Is there a way I can embed Java code inside a YAML file to be processed at runtime.

Tags: java, yaml, erb

I know ruby has this facility using ERB. But does Java have this capability?
I'm trying to do something like this:

MY.yaml
CURRENT_DATE: <%=LocalDateTime.now()%>

Comment: Unlike Ruby, Java is a compiled language. I think your best bet is to use a templating library like Velocity or Freemarker.

Comment: Java has a built-in Javascript interpreter - so if the code in your YAML were Javascript, you could hand it off to the JS interpreter to evaluate...

Comment: Please specify what kind of processing you mean. It is trivial to embed Java (source) code in a YAML file. The program loading the YAML just needs to be able to do the processing, that is easy if processing means extracting all uppercase characters from the text, and difficult if you want to compile and run the code within the program doing the YAML loading.

Answer (score 0):

Ya, the classic way is using Java server pages https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaServer_Pages
Something like

```
Date : <% Date() %>
myArray:
<% for (int i=1; i<4; i++) { %>
    - This  is <% i %> th element.
<% } %>
```

For modern curly bracket based templating use www.thymeleaf.org, or better JTwig with double curly braces and other cool features

```
 CurrentDate: {{ "now"|date("m/d/Y") }}
```

https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/date.html

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar requirement where a YAML had an expression which needed to be parsed in runtime in Java.

We ended up using [MVEL](http://www.treselle.com/blog/java-mvel/) for this. We read the contents of the yaml and passed the expression to MVEL. Its syntax is quite similar to that of Java.

You could also try other template library like [Velocity Template](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/1.7/user-guide.html).